# How to mock instance methods called by the tested method so you test only one thing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

Imagine that I have the following class:

```
class ToTest : IToTest
{
    public string MethodA()
    {
        return "Test";
    }

    public int MethodB()
    {
        returns a random number;
    }

    public string MethodC()
    {
        return this.MethodA + " " + this.MethodB.ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm testing now MethodC so I understand that I should mock MethodA and MethodB of my current instance so I only test MethodC validity right?

I'm using Rhino and I did the following:

```
ToTest testedObject = new ToTest();

testedObject.Expect(t => t.MethodA).Returns("AString");
testedObject.Expect(t => t.MethodB).Returns(1324");

Assert.AreEqual("AString 1324", testedObject.MethodC());
```

But I get an error correctly saying that the testedObject is not a Mock.

Is the approach right? How should I proceeed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, please do not write test cases like this. Unit tests are not about "testing just one thing", they are all about ensuring that each test is a unit, ie it has no influence on any other test.

All your tests should be interested in is the public API of your class. Do not test internals or private methods, they are part of the inner workings of your class, and do not try to mock parts of your class in order to test other parts. Your test of `MethodC` *must* indirectly test `MethodA` and `MethodB` too, otherwise your test is meaningless.

For anyone interested in an excellent talk on how to write good unit tests, I'd recommend setting aside an hour and watching the ['Ian Cooper: TDD, where did it all go wrong' video](http://vimeo.com/68375232) from NDC 2013.

Comment: Not sure if I get you. I have alredy two tests testing MethodA and MethodB so why should I try them again in MethodC? If I have an error on MethodA I want MethodA test to fail, not MethodC that's why I was focusing on testing the MethodC functionality. All 3 are public methods.

Comment: So is it right to test more than one method with one unit test?

Comment: MethodC invokes MethodA, therefore to test MethodC, you must invoke MethodA. The test is meaningless if you do not. You are testing MethodC. The fact it invokes the other two methods is an implementation detail that your test should not be concerned with.

Comment: But then with MethodA wrong MethodA test and MethodC test will fail. Is this considered ok?

Comment: @SoMoS, absolutely it is. The MethodC test fails because there is a problem with the inner workings of MethodC. The fact that the MethodA test fails as well guides you to where the problem is.

Comment: I must agree with SoMoS here that it might in some cases be helpful to test MethodC only. I.e if MethodA is generating the data that MethodC is working on, mocking that data might really help in testing MethodC. But this is just maybe a case where they should be moved to different classes.

Answer (score 3):

Based off the example that you are having us imagine, the simple answer to your question is your approach is not correct.  By having the trouble you are experiencing, the code is trying to tell you that you have some mixed concerns in the code that are coupled too tightly together, and that instead of having cohesive code, you are having adhesive code. (Glenn Vanderburg has a nice blog entry on the topic of cohesion found at http://www.vanderburg.org/Blog/Software/Development/cohesion.rdoc)

If you are feeling the need to mock out `MethodA` and `MethodB` to test `MethodC` this is a signal that one of a few things, possibly all of them even, are missing in the code.

The first thing the difficulty is telling you is that `MethodC` may likely be in the wrong location in the code.  `MethodC` may very well belong to another object which takes and object with `MethodA` and `MethodB` as a dependency, either through constructor injection, or parameter injection.

The second thing that stands out, is that you are having trouble testing `MethodC` because `MethodB` has a dependency on what would lead me to think of being a global/singleton behavior.  You have defined `MethodB` as `returns a random number`, instead of taking a dependency on a object that fills a role of `NumberGenerator`.  By explicitly calling out the dependency on this role (Interface), it would allow you to pass in different implementations of the role depending on the usage. Three obvious implementations that could be used and easily swapped out depending on if it is production code or test code would be:

- a `RandomNumberGenerator`: returns a random number every time it is called,
- a `SequentialNumberGenerator`: returns the next number in a sequence (of which multiple types of sequences could be generated), such as increasing by a set number every time, or some kind of a mathamatical sequence, e.g. Fibbonacci or Collatz
- a `ContsistantNumberGenerator`: returns the same number every single time it is called, which is *very* useful in testing.

The third thing that your example may be telling you is a refinement of the previous issue, calling out that you have a dependency on not only mutable state which you can't control, but non-deterministic mutable state, which you would have no means of coercing into a given state, even by sending a number of other messages to objects to try to get into that state.  I know of no messages that you can send that will setup the environment to return a desired *random number* upon the next call to get it; even if there is such a way, the amount of setup that would be required would obscure what you are actually trying to test.

I hope that one of these suggestions help you address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work for two reasons (Assuming you're using Rhino.Mocks):

- You cannot mock a method that is not virtual.
- You can only test whole instances (or static members). That means, when you want to individually test methods inside the class without the others, you need some workaround, i.e. by providing a factory or by moving MethodC into a different class than MethodA and MethodB.

Comment: I agree but seems strange to me as testing just one thing on each test sounds as a Mantra for testers and this looks a pretty common issue.

Comment: By the way, I have a IToTest interface if this helps. Added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A working code for your example will be something like this:

```
public class ToTest
{
    private Random random = new Random();

    public virtual string MethodA()
    {
        return "Test";
    }

    public virtual int MethodB()
    {
        return random.Next();
    }

    public virtual string MethodC()
    {
        return MethodA() + " " + MethodB();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_MethodC()
    {
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        ToTest testedObject = mocks.CreateMock<ToTest>();

        testedObject.Expect(t => t.MethodA()).Return("AString");
        testedObject.Expect(t => t.MethodB()).Return(1324);

        Assert.AreEqual("AString 1324", testedObject.MethodC());
    }
}
```

**BUT!**

This will not pass the test. And the cause is that *Rhino.Mocks*, like most other mocking frameworks, excluding MS Moles/Shims, TypeMock and others using profiler API, cannot enforce the type to see the mocked methods from inside. This is because mocking frameworks create a proxy type around the original one and inject the mocking logic into the proxy, not into the original type itself.

So, as suggested, you should extract *MethodA* and *MethodB* into a separate dependencies, in case you have something to test inside *MethodC*.

Another, perfectly viable way is to derive from the *ToTest* class, override the *MethodA* and *MethodB*, and test the instance of the derived class.

Comment: You are simply replicating MethodA and MethodB's functionality in your mocks. In a more complex scenario, you might get that function replication wrong, potentially resulting in the MethodC passing a test, but failing in production, which makes the test redundant and gives a false assurance that all is OK. Alternatively, if the behaviour of MethodA or MethodB is changes, it might result in a fragile test that fails, even though the code under test is functioning correctly. Such mocking is bad practice.

Comment: @DavidArno Usually, I would like to test the *MethodC* in this way in order to ensure that it takes care of invalid input properly. For example, when *MethodC* is concrete, but *A* and *B* are virtual, I would like to ensure that is throws exception on *null* received from the *A*. And that will be probably the only test for this case. And, a thing to remember, this is one of the approaches you can use without massive refactoring/buying expensive licenses, while working with legacy code.

Comment: +1 Because of the last sentence. With the test class deriving from the original method, Mocking of MethodA and MethodB works like it should. And no, you won't copy the _implementation_ of these.

Comment: @galenus, if MethodA and MethodB were virtual, then I'd expect then to use private methods and I'd have MethodC use those private methods too. Still no excuse for mocking part of the class when testing other parts.

Comment: @DavidArno I believe there is a pure way and there is a convenient way. If you want (and have the privilege) to do everything by book, you choose the pure one. If you *know* what you do and got to have results with some constraints around, you choose the most convenient way. Sometimes (not in this case), it is convenient to mock parts of the class. For example, when the method being mocked is a factory method, used not only by external consumer, but by the type declaring the method as well. Of course, then the question of right design arises, but sometimes it is a given reality.